# Why does this java regular expression not work?

Tags: java, regex

Why does this Pattern not match the port in my URL?

```
public class PatternTest {
    private Pattern PORT_STRING_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(":\\d+/");

    private boolean hasPort(String url) {
        return PORT_STRING_PATTERN.matcher(url).matches();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUrlHasPort() {
        assertTrue("does not have port", hasPort("http://www.google.com:80/"));
    }
}
```

If I change the pattern to `Pattern.compile("^.+:\\d+/")` it does match.  Why do I need the `^.+` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [`Matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29), which is documented as:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

You don't want to match the entire region - you just want to find a match *within* the region.

I think you probably want to be calling [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) instead:

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.

Comment: Yup, classical mistake, and (imho) mistake from the Java API designers to start with.

Comment: @fge: In my humble opinion, I don't think it is a mistake. Since "end of string" is needed for validation (when you use `match` in other languages), `$` is usually used while it doesn't always mean the absolute end of string. If the string ends with a line terminator sequence, then `$` can match right before it.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Having the two calls available makes sense. Calling the "match entire region" call `matches` may be a mistake though.

Answer (score 4):

It is because `Matcher#matches` attempts to match entire input. You need `matcher#find()` instead.